# MySQL Query getting slower

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, websocket

We are sending the below select statement as an XML message on a timer through a dedicated socket (9030). The query worked well initially but since we have been running more PHP files in parallel the below message has slowed down, it now sends approx 30 seconds after it is supposed to. This can be rectified by deleting data within the database but I was hoping there was another solution that can be suggested here.

```
 private function doEventStop() {

        $sql = "update SessionLogs
                set EventStatusID = 0
                where resultID > 0
                ";
            db_query($sql);

            $timestamp = time();
            $sentCnt = 0;
            foreach ($this->myusers as $user) {
                $sql2 = "SELECT SessionLogs.sessionid, SessionLogs.eventid, ResultPackage.Winner,
                    EventStatus.EventStatus, GameStatus.GameStatus,
                    ResultPackage.T3Way,
ResultPackage.CorrectScore,
ResultPackage.HighestScoringPeriod,
ResultPackage.Overtime,
ResultPackage.MHPN2P5,
ResultPackage.MHPN1P5,
ResultPackage.MHP1P5,
ResultPackage.MHP2P5,
ResultPackage.MAPN2P5,
ResultPackage.MAPN1P5,
ResultPackage.MAP1P5,
ResultPackage.MAP2P5,
ResultPackage.MOTG1P5,
ResultPackage.MOTG2P5,
ResultPackage.MOTG3P5,
ResultPackage.MOTG4P5,
ResultPackage.MOTG5P5,
ResultPackage.MOTG6P5,
ResultPackage.MUTG1P5,
ResultPackage.MUTG2P5,
ResultPackage.MUTG3P5,
ResultPackage.MUTG4P5,
ResultPackage.MUTG5P5,
ResultPackage.MUTG6P5,
ResultPackage.MHFPN0P5,
ResultPackage.MHFP0P5,
ResultPackage.MAFPN0P5,
ResultPackage.MAFP0P5,
ResultPackage.MO1P5,
ResultPackage.MU1P5

          FROM  SessionLogs
                    LEFT JOIN ResultPackage ON SessionLogs.resultid = ResultPackage.ResultID and ResultPackage.PackageID = '{$user->packageid}'
                    LEFT JOIN EventStatus ON SessionLogs.eventstatusid = EventStatus.EventStatusID
                    LEFT JOIN BetStatus ON SessionLogs.GameStatusID= GameStatus.GameStatusID
                    LEFT JOIN EventInfo ON SessionLogs.slotid = EventInfo.SlotID and EventInfo.PackageID = '{$user->packageid}'
                    Order by eventstart desc
                    LIMIT 1";

                $res = db_fetch($sql2);
                $returnXML = '<EventStop timestamp="'.$timestamp.'">';
                foreach ($res as $eventInfo) {
                    $returnXML .= '<Event sessionid="'.$eventInfo['sessionid'].'" eventid="'.$eventInfo['eventid'].'" Winner="'.$eventInfo['Winner'].'"
                    EventStatus="'.$eventInfo['EventStatus'].'" BetStatus="'.$eventInfo['GameStatus'].'" T3Way="'.$eventInfo['T3Way'].'"
                    CorrectScore="'.$eventInfo['CorrectScore'].'"
HighestScoringPeriod="'.$eventInfo['HighestScoringPeriod'].'"
Overtime="'.$eventInfo['Overtime'].'"
MHPN2P5="'.$eventInfo['MHPN2P5'].'"
MHPN1P5="'.$eventInfo['MHPN1P5'].'"
MHP1P5="'.$eventInfo['MHP1P5'].'"
MHP2P5="'.$eventInfo['MHP2P5'].'"
MAPN2P5="'.$eventInfo['MAPN2P5'].'"
MAPN1P5="'.$eventInfo['MAPN1P5'].'"
MAP1P5="'.$eventInfo['MAP1P5'].'"
MAP2P5="'.$eventInfo['MAP2P5'].'"
MOTG1P5="'.$eventInfo['MOTG1P5'].'"
MOTG2P5="'.$eventInfo['MOTG2P5'].'"
MOTG3P5="'.$eventInfo['MOTG3P5'].'"
MOTG4P5="'.$eventInfo['MOTG4P5'].'"
MOTG5P5="'.$eventInfo['MOTG5P5'].'"
MOTG6P5="'.$eventInfo['MOTG6P5'].'"
MUTG1P5="'.$eventInfo['MUTG1P5'].'"
MUTG2P5="'.$eventInfo['MUTG2P5'].'"
MUTG3P5="'.$eventInfo['MUTG3P5'].'"
MUTG4P5="'.$eventInfo['MUTG4P5'].'"
MUTG5P5="'.$eventInfo['MUTG5P5'].'"
MUTG6P5="'.$eventInfo['MUTG6P5'].'"
MHFPN0P5="'.$eventInfo['MHFPN0P5'].'"
MHFP0P5="'.$eventInfo['MHFP0P5'].'"
MAFPN0P5="'.$eventInfo['MAFPN0P5'].'"
MAFP0P5="'.$eventInfo['MAFP0P5'].'"
MO1P5="'.$eventInfo['MO1P5'].'"
MU1P5="'.$eventInfo['MU1P5'].'"
                    />';
                }
                $returnXML .= "</EventStop>";
                $this->send($user, $returnXML);
                $this->doLogMessage($user, 6);
                $sentCnt++;
            }
            echo "Sent EventStop message to {$sentCnt} users.\n";
    }
    public function __destruct()
```

Comment: This line makes no sense - care to explain? `LEFT JOIN BetStatus ON SessionLogs.GameStatusID= GameStatus.GameStatusID`

Comment: And presumably eventstart belongs to eventinfo?

Comment: Note also that a database table is not a spreadsheet. This schema would surely benefit from some optimisation

Comment: Start by inserting some logging statements, to determine whether it's the first SQL query or the second that's causing slowness (my bet is on the first).

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks this is incorrect. Should read:   LEFT JOIN GamesStatus ON SessionLogs.GameStatusID= GameStatus.GameStatusID

Comment: @Parsifal, thank you for the suggestion. I will implement some logging here. The Update statement should only be updating 1 row at a time but there is currently 60050 rows in that table so you could be correct

Comment: @Strawberry, any suggestions on optimisation would be much appreciated. Thank you for your comments so far

Comment: Without know more about what the constituent parts of a string like 'MHPN2P5' represent, it's hard to advise further.